Member "transactionCount" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract TransactionsContract)
I am getting the error:
Line: 49 in TransactionsContract.sol
Member "transactionCount" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract TransactionsContract).
even though I have declared transactionsCount as public and I have also imported the TransactionContract. I looked up on forums but didn't find anything suitable.
Any help is greatly appreciated! 
TransactionsContract.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TransactionsContract{
enum TransactionStatus { InTransit, Delivered, Returned, RequestedRefund, DeliveryRejected }

struct Transaction {
uint256 transactionId;
uint256 productId;
TransactionStatus status;
}

mapping(uint256 => Transaction) public transactions;
uint256 public transactionCount;

}

ProductContract.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TransactionsContract{
enum TransactionStatus { InTransit, Delivered, Returned, RequestedRefund, DeliveryRejected }

struct Transaction {
uint256 transactionId;
uint256 productId;
TransactionStatus status;
}

mapping(uint256 => Transaction) public transactions;
uint256 public transactionCount;

}


You haven't provided the code for ProductContract, instead provided TransactionsContract twice.
